# Include GitHub repos you've contributed heavily to on your profile

Tags: git, github

I have a very simple question. There are a few projects I've worked heavily on as the primary developer with some friends, but I didn't create the repo. For employment purposes, I'd like these repositories to show up on my profile so employers can see what I've created. What's the best way to go about this? Should I fork it?

Comment: If you've made commits they'll show up in your dashboard/contribution graph, even if you don't own the repo.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+contribution